# How to catch CONSTRAINT Exception when adding duplicate unique id with VB

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem that adding a new ROW with duplicate UNIQUE id throws CONSTRAINTException that I cannot always catch.. Randomly general exception halts my VB software, sometimes catching works. here is my code.

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_MouseUp()
      try
      DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = InputBox("give new product id")
      Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error ") <-- never comes here!!
      End Try

end sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(..) Handles DataGridView1.DataError

        e.ThrowException = False <-- randomly comes here!!
        Dim v As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
        v.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = "The value is wrong"
        v.BeginEdit(False)
        MessageBox.Show("error 2") 

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct this code to avoid ever even adding duplicate rows.  Just swallowing the error (even if you can) is a bad idea.

Comment: ok, so the recommended way to avoid adding duplicate row, is to execute a query beforehand,  instead of not trusting exception handled?

Comment: For a product ID (without knowing much about your db), I would expect it would be auto-numbered. Is that possible?

Comment: That is not a reliable approach.  Even if you check immediately before-hand, you still cannot be sure that someone else has not slipped in and added the same primary key value.  You have to be able to deal with errors from the DB execution.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first how do you know that the database INSERT command is being executed within the context of the first procedure?  I don't see anything there that would force the changes back to the database.  Are you getting an unhandled exception with a stack dump that shows that it was called from that routine (and yet not handled)?  Otherwise, I would say that there is a good chance that the INSERT is not being executed until sometime after that routine.

Secondly, it appears to me that the DataGridView1_DataError will squelch the error anyway.  I beleive that the _DataError event will be invoked before it returns to the code that caused the INSERT to be executed and that "e.ThrowException = False" is spposed to prevent any repropagation of the exception.